# Javascript File to String to File to URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, file, base64, blob

i will convert the image to string and send it to server from ajax,
then when i want to get it from server i will and convert it to file than convert it to image url
so i made below test and that is not working.

so i need your help

```html
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <input type="file"/>Please input a "png" image for test<br>
    <img src=""/>
    <hr>
    <button state="working">Working</button>
    <button state="notworking">Not Working</button>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $.FileToString = async (File, callback) => {
          const reader = new FileReader()
          reader.onload = async () => {
              callback(await reader.result)
          }
          reader.readAsText(File)
      }
      
      $.StringToFile = (String, type)=>{
          return new Blob([String],{type:type})
      }
      
      $.FileToUrl = async (File,callback)=>{
          const reader = new FileReader()
          reader.onload = async ()=>{
              callback(await reader.result)
          }
          reader.readAsDataURL(File)
      }
    </script>
    <script>
      $("button[state='notworking']").on("click",()=>{
        $.FileToString($("input[type='file']")[0].files[0],(string)=>{
         $.FileToUrl($.StringToFile(String,"image/png"),(a)=>($("img")[0].src = a))
        })
      })
      
      $("button[state='working']").on("click",()=>{
        $.FileToUrl($("input[type='file']")[0].files[0],a=>($("img")[0].src = a))
      })
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please give server side implementation and what do you want to achieve after sending it to server, do you want to save the image as blob in DB. Please elaborate.

Comment: Sorry but why "i will convert the image to string and send it to server from ajax"? Just send the File as binary through a multipart request. And if you wish to display the File content in your page then use a [blobURI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL). You never need a dataURI version of your binary data. (Yes in some really rare cases you could need it, but to keep it simple, let's say you don't until you know you do).

Comment: @amy dude no problem on server only solve second button's problem

Comment: @Kaiido im using "spring boot response requests" for receiving data on server and sending trough ajax as json is more ez for me

EDIT: and actually blob uri is not working

Comment: Dunno spring boot but a fast google search [lead to this](https://www.callicoder.com/spring-boot-file-upload-download-rest-api-example/) where on the front side they're sending the files as multipart just like I told you you should do. Also "is not working" doesn't mean anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use Array buffers as mediator

```html
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <input type="file"/>Please input a "png" image for test<br>
    <img src=""/>
    <hr>
    <button state="working">Working</button>
    <button state="notworking">now works</button>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $.FileToArrayBuffer = (File, callback) => {
            const reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = async () => {
                callback(await reader.result);
            }
            reader.readAsArrayBuffer(File)
        }

        $.ArrayBufferToString = (ArrayBuffer, callback)=>{
            btoa(new Uint8Array(blob).reduce(async (data,byte)=>{
                callback(await (data + String.fromCharCode(byte)));
            }));
        }

        $.StringToArrayBuffer = (String)=>{
            var enc = TextEncoder();
            return enc.encode(String);
        }

        $.ArrayBufferToFile = (ArrayBuffer)=>{
            return new Blob([ArrayBuffer])
        }

        $.FileToUrl = (File,callback)=>{
            const reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = async ()=>{
                callback(await reader.result);
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(File);
        }
    </script>
    <script>
        $("button[state='notworking']").on("click",()=>{
            $.FileToArrayBuffer($("input[type='file']")[0].files[0],(arraybuffer)=>{
                $.FileToUrl($.ArrayBufferToFile(arraybuffer,"image/png"),(a)=>($("img")[0].src = a))
            })
        })
      
      $("button[state='working']").on("click",()=>{
        $.FileToUrl($("input[type='file']")[0].files[0],a=>($("img")[0].src = a))
      })
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```